# Rate equation of a radical

Tags: physical-chemistry, combustion

> Consider the following elementary reaction mechanism where both the forward and reverse reaction mechanism are important
>   $$\ce{CO + O2<->[1] CO2 + O}$$
>   $$\ce{O + H2O<->[2] OH + OH}$$
>   $$\ce{CO + OH<->[3] CO2 + H}$$
>   $$\ce{H + O2<->[4] OH + O}$$
>   How many chemical rate equations are need to determine the chemical evolution of a system defined by this mechanism? Write out the rate equation for the hydroxyl radical.

This question is from the book  Introduction to Combustion: Concepts and Applications by Stephen R. Turns.

My answer to the second part is 
$$\frac{d[\ce{OH}]}{dt}=( k_{f_2}[\ce{O}][\ce{H2O}]+k_{r_3}[\ce{CO2}][\ce{H}]+ k_{f_4}[\ce{H}][\ce{O2}] ) - (k_{r_2}[\ce{OH}][\ce{OH}]+k_{f_3}[\ce{CO}][\ce{OH}] +k_{r_4}[\ce{OH}][\ce{O}])$$

Is this correct?

$k_f$ is the elementary forward rate coefficient

$k_r$ is the elementary reverse rate coefficient

[ ] refers to concentration

Comment: Second reaction stems from first one so it also should be present in equation, afaik.

Comment: Hei,  second reaction is included in the rate equation I wrote

Comment: I meant include _first_.  Gah, language is such a terrible tool.

Comment: Is there a difference between the rate equation and net reaction rate ? Because What I wrote is the net reaction rate and I have been told that my answer was wrong.

Comment: I would have a factor of 2 in the two terms for reaction 2 in the OH balance.